# Components with and without events

Tags: javascript, css, events, vuejs3, event-handling

I work on Vue3 and want to find a way to distinguish between components with an event and components without an event.

Like for example

```
<vue-box text="No event"/>
```

or

```
<vue-box text="with event" click="myEvent"/>
```

The thing is that i want to add a special class for the latter component (like an effect on hoover for instance)

So i want to figure out a way to tell if a component has an event or not.

So tell me, what can i do?

What does NOT work: this.$attr.myEvent, as this crashes with the event declaration and adds up warnings in the console.

Also, i know that i can use a prop to tell which box is clickable or not, but i would rather avoid adding props.

Comment: What is the use case that it needs to be programmatically added?  You typed out the click handler, why not the class?

Comment: Because declaring a class outside said component's stylesheet can be seem as bad practice. I work on a group project and my group doesn't like component classes being declared outside it's respective page. They explicitly asked me to avoid this kind of solution.